# python 3 Beautiful Soup, currency symbol

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm parsing a page using beautiful soap 4.4.
all the local language symbols are shown correctly. except the currency sign - for it i'm getting a symbols like this:

```
à¸¿1,500
à¸¿120
à¸¿790,000
```

related code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', ''), 'lxml')
items_list = soup.findAll('div', id=re.compile('^post_'))
price = item.div.contents[1].contents[1].text
```

what is the right way to get the currency symbols?

upd. html:

```
<div><div class="_sz6">à¸¿790,000</div></div>
```

Comment: post your HTML code

Comment: Check the encoding of that HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the encoding of the response is 'utf-8'

```
if r.encoding != 'utf-8':
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'
```